# What do you call this button-shaped thing?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests, american-english

I was changing the back light bulb on my car ,and I was struggling to unbutton this button-shaped thing . what do you call this button-shaped thing in English?

It looks like a tack or a fastener. The car manufacturer might have a specific name for it.
( I'm curious to know )

[image: button-shaped thing]

Comment: I'd call it a ***stud** fastening / clip / closure* (push the stud "head" in and it "locks", pull it out and the outer part can be detached).

Comment: @FumbleFingers , exactly

Comment: I put *fastening* first because I'd be more likely to use that in the context of the thing that holds the car boot lining in place, but I'd probably say *stud clip* n the context of, say, earrings. And *stud closure* in more "abstract" contexts where you're just talking about how two sheets could be bonded along an edge (in an engineering drawing, say).

Comment: @fumbleFingers , thanks.  fastner bumper push clips or something like that http://www.aliexpress.com/w/wholesale-push-clips.html

Comment: If it's pulled it "could" be what is called a blind rivet.  But it does look like common plastic fastener used a lot in automotive applications.

Comment: Is this what you were trying to remove, or has that bit been removed in this photograph (and this is fixed)?

Comment: @Edwin Ashworth, I had removed it a bit before i took the picture

Comment: Then I'm not sure it's a 'rivet fastener' as shown on a Google image search.

Comment: Is it a coat hanger, located just above the rear passenger doors of some vehicles near the back-seat light bulbs?

Comment: @Lawrence , No , it's located inside the trunk to keep the cover tight

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is called a rivet fastener.  If it is plastic, you can call it a plastic rivet fastener.  If it is metal, you can call it a metal rivet fastener.

Comment: You are answering your own question?

Comment: @NVZ, that's what I found after I had asked the car service center .

Comment: @NVZ It's acceptable and even encouraged in the right context. See [this link](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/).

Comment: @Lawrence Thanks, I didn't know that.

Answer (score 1):

A blog post titled [Peugeot 206 Rear Light Replacement](http://philsworkbench.blogspot.in/2013/09/peugeot-206-rear-light-replacement.html) shows the actual image you posted in the question. In it they call it a [**plastic bung**](http://www.ebay.co.uk/bhp/plastic-bungs). But *rivet fastener* seems like the better name here since *bung* may not be understood by many.

Comment: I actually came across the same phrase " plastic bung " , but some of my native English speaker friends told me it seems to be wierd .

Comment: I see. **Bung** may not be used internationally. But I just wanted to show you what the blogger himself called it.